# Feedback on ERD design and questions

Tags: database-schema, database-normalization, erd

I am working on an ERD of my database of films.What disadvantages does having multiple columns to store similar data bring?
[image: Initial ERD]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your 1st diagram, if you are sure that the maximum number of genres for each film is "3", directors are "4" and writers are "3", then it will be ok.

In your 1st diagram, your PersonID is char(9), it is ok.... but usually coders will use say an integer (auto incremented) as the key so you do not need to use program codes to check duplicate ID. (as in your other diagrams)

For the 3rd and 4th pictures (are they the same ?), you store the directors, writers and genres in separate tables, yes it is needed if there is no limit on the number of directors, writers and genres for each film.

Comment: Thank for your answer, Ken. The first diagram is not mine, it is a diagram that is said to have multiple columns for similar values (genre1,genre2...) and the question is: what disadvantages does this design bring? And it asks me to solve this by introducing a design which does not have many columns, but has the same attributes. The second and the third diagrams are my ways of solving this and I am not sure which one is more suitable, hence the request for a feedback=)

Comment: The disadvantages of the 1st diagram are : (A) if there are more than 3 genres , or more than 4 directors, or more than 3 writers per film , then the database table cannot store the data. (B) there can be unnecessary data redundancy (for example if a particular film only has 2 directors, then the data field of the 3rd and 4th directors will be wasting storage space)

In my opinion ,your 3rd diagram is correct from a practical perspective.